# android : save svg file from web and save on a file

Tags: android, file, svg, bitmap

i want to save a svg file from web to a file and then show it from file. i use this code to save a png file :

```
OutputStream fos = null;
File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(),FilenameUtils.getBaseName(url.toString())+FilenameUtils.getExtension(url.toString()));
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bos);
bos.flush();
bos.close();
```

what should i do for svg file ?

Comment: You are saving the bitmap of a drawable to a .png file. What has that to do with downloading a file from web?

Comment: @greenapps i get file from web and saved it on a drawable now i want save it on a file

Comment: Are you downloading an .svg file from web and putting it in a drawable? And after that you want to save it to file as .svg?

Comment: @greenapps  i save it on drawable and then show it on image view https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/   i want to save file for next time i show it from file

Comment: What is 'it'? Please be more exact. And just answer my question.

Comment: @greenapps  ok , i have svg file on web and i want to show this file on a image view. i receive this svg from web and save on drawable and then show this drawable on a imageView. i want to save this drawable on a file and next time show image from this file.

Comment: You better download the .svg directly to file.

Comment: @greenapps, how can i download .svg file

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
PictureDrawable pd = (PictureDrawable) imageView.getPicture();
Picture picture = pd.getPicture();
picture.writeToStream(os);
```

**However you should not do this.**  `writeToStream()` is deprecated (as is `createFromStream()`).  I presume the reason is that the format of a Picture may change in the future and any saved pictures may no longer load.  If you are just using it for temporary caching while the app is running, then that *may* be okay.

But it would be better, as @greenapps says, to cache the original SVGs.